# Can you find the missing letters?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, letters, letter-sequence, number-property

A pattern of letters has had letters 10 through 20 deleted. Your job is to find out what letters should go in spots 10-20. Here is the pattern:

a, b, c, d, d, d, f, e, f, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, h, j, i, i, j, j, j, j, k, k, j, k, l, k, l, l, l, k, m, l, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, n, m, n, n, n, n, o, n, o, o, n, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, p, p, p, p, p, p, q, q, p, q, p, q, r, q, r, q, q, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, s, s, s, r, s, s, s, s, s, s, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, u, u, u, t, u, v, u, u, u, u, v, u, u, v, v, v, v, v, v, w, v, v, w, v, v, w, w, w, w, w, x, w, x, w, w, w, w, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, y, x, x, x, x, y, y, y, x, y, y, y, y, y, z, y, y, y, y, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, . . .

You may use any method or technique to solve this. It can be solved deterministically with only the information above.

Hint:

> You may consider converting the letters into numbers.

Comment: It reminds me vaguely of the [Fibonacci Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence), but it's not quite the same.